# Error solc not installed and cannot connect to github

Tags: python, solidity, smartcontracts, brownie

I am trying to compile Solidity Code using brownie in VSCode. I installed the Solidity compiler through the extensions in VSCode. Whenever I do brownie compile I see below error:

ConnectionError: Solc not installed and cannot connect to github

Contract I have created is as below:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.24;

contract HashForEther {

    function withdrawWinnings() {
        // Winner if the last 8 hex characters of the address are 0. 
        require(uint32(msg.sender) == 0);
        _sendWinnings();
     }

     function _sendWinnings() {
         msg.sender.transfer(address(this).balance);
     }
}
```

I am new to solidity and smart contracts. Am I using different compiler version in contract to what brownie is using to compile? How do I know which version to use?

Comment: brownie compiler version and the contract's compiler version should be the same. We are already at 0.8, I suggest you to go with a more up-to-date tutorial maybe from Patric collins freecode camp one on yt.

Comment: VSCode is not allowing me to change the version at all in the contract.

Comment: what are you talking about man? vscode is an editor.

Comment: Yes but if I use any other version it is giving me error. I could use >=0.7.0 if I change that to 0.8.0 it gives error.